# Strange circle(arc) around camera in the viewport render and in final renders

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I have some weird arc around camera. It gets more obvious when I zoom in the camera, and become bigger when zoom out. I checked face orientation and its fine. So I couldn't find a solution.

Edit1. I checked object visibility and its ok. Adding blend file link.

[Blend File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ivrF6i7WjVzFbvZjmJMJQ7_gixp-i4b0/view?usp=sharing)
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, it's hard to help with just this render image. Please post a screenshot in wireframe view and a screenshot of your scene 3d view. Also make sure all hidden objects are also set to not render (disabled camera icon in the outliner)

Comment: Yeah, I did it. Also adding my blend file.